# Locating ARP cache on an android device

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, mac-address, ip-address

If you are familiar with the command prompt in windows, there is an command that can used to see the ARP (Address Resolution Protocol) Cache in the command prompt i.e. arp -a. It is supposedly a table where static/dynamic  MAC-to-IP address associations are stored.

In android 5.1 is there a similar ARP cache also? If there is, how can I view the current list of Mac-IP address associations lets say using a Samsung Galaxy phone for example?

Comment: I can't test this now, but the file `/proc/net/arp` should contain the information you look for. You can read it with any proper file manager or Terminal Emulator (use `cat` for reading the file). You don't need root to read that one file.

Comment: I can't find `/proc/net/arp` in my phone. How do I access it?

Comment: Another possibility is the command `ip neighbor`. It lists all IPs and MAC addresses in the neighborhood.

Comment: How do I run "ip neighbor" command using Java code on Android App?